# Asymptotic equality

Tags: asymptotics

Why do we have this:
For $x = o(1)$, $1 - x = \exp(-x-O(x^2))$?
I know the idea is from the Taylor's formula, but it sounds weird to me. I would like to know a clear explanation for it?

To be more clear, I know that these two things are asymptotically equal, as a calculus problem, but I like to look at it from the reverse; I mean I want to know how can I create an equality like this? It is not clear here how can we take inside the exponential function the term $O(x^2)$?

Comment: $x=o(1)$ is just a fancy way of saying $x\to 0$. The rest is $\log(1-x) = -x + O(x^2)$.

Comment: @ Normal Human : Thank you! I know that these two things are asymptotically equal, when $x$ tends to zero, but how should I know that I can take $O(x^2)$ into the exponential function?! It is not clear, since if we use the Taylor's series for the exponential function, then we will have simply $O(x^2) $, not $\exp(O(x^2))$!!!? Instead of looking at this like a calculus problem, I want to see how can I create an equality like this while working with asymptotic stuff?